# How can I divide up my C# file when it has rendering and functionality all together?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an application with code for a page like this:

```
public partial class PhrasesFrameRenderer : Frame
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    private int answeredPhraseCount;
    private int correctAns;

    public PhrasesFrameRenderer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AS.PhrasesFrameRenderer = this;
        phraseStackLayout.BindingContext = AS.themeColor;
        faveLabel.Text = FontAwesome.FAHeartO;

        // Favorites

        DataTrigger triggerTrue = new DataTrigger(typeof(Label))
        {
            Value = true,
            Binding = new Binding() { Path = "Favorite" }
        };
        Setter setterTrue = new Setter()
        {
            Property = Label.TextColorProperty,
            Value = Color.Red
        };

        DataTrigger triggerFalse = new DataTrigger(typeof(Label))
        {
            Value = false,
            Binding = new Binding() { Path = "Favorite" }
        };

        Setter setterFalse = new Setter()
        {
            Property = Label.TextColorProperty,
            Value = Color.Red
        };

        triggerFalse.Setters.Clear();
        triggerTrue.Setters.Clear();

        triggerTrue.Setters.Add(setterTrue); 
        triggerFalse.Setters.Add(setterFalse);

        favoriteLabel.Triggers.Add(triggerTrue);
        favoriteLabel.Triggers.Add(triggerFalse);

        correctButton.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
        {
            App.DB.IncrementScore(AS.cfs, AS.phrase);
            correctAns++;
            AS.pointsCount[(int)AS.cfs]++;
            scoreCountLabel.Text = FontAwesome.FAStop.Repeat(correctAns);
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), () =>
            {
                switch (AS.cardOrder)
                {
                    case CardOrder.FirstToLast:
                        AS.orderPhraseIndex++;
                        AS.phraseIndexList.Add(AS.orderPhraseIndex);
                        getPhraseFirstToLast();
                        break;
                    case CardOrder.Random:
                        getRandomNumber();
                        getRandomPhrase();
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            });
        };
```

the C# code for rendering and the C# code for the page logic are all combined into one large file and it's difficult to debug / maintain.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can restructure this.  Is this the same for most Xamarin form applications?

Comment: If that's a question about Xamarin.Forms, you could use MVVM + ViewModel to split that. If you're asking more about C# and code, I think what you can easily do is to use partial classes and name them like `Form1.View.cs` and `Form1.Logic.cs`. Sometimes this might help

Comment: If I do this then I am bit confused as I can only have one constructor and I think I need to set up the C# for the view and the C# for the logic in the constructor.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, if you split the code file, you will have the constructor with the UI and logic code in one of the files. If you want to separate out the logic (sound like you do), then you should look into MVVM and create ViewModels to encapsulate logic for each of your pages. You can read more about it: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter18/.

Comment: You can create a function Let say Init and call it from your constructor. Init can be in different file. But I agree with other guys, you might look at MVVM patern